# createPdf from already created excel using syncfusion in winrt

Tags: c#, excel, pdf, winrt-xaml, syncfusion

I am using syncfusion way to create excel sheets. Now I want to create pdf with same format. I looked at sample code of syncfusion and its very complex. So Is there any way to use already created excels to generate pdfs.

I used this code to create excel

```
Assembly executingAssembly = typeof(MainPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            Stream inputStream = executingAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("CRICKIT.Assets.TVM.xlsx");

            IWorkbook book = await this.excelEngine.Excel.Workbooks.OpenAsync(inputStream);
            inputStream.Dispose();

            //Create Template Marker Processor
            ITemplateMarkersProcessor marker = book.CreateTemplateMarkersProcessor();
            //Binding the business object with the marker.
            marker.AddVariable("TVMManager", App.ViewModel.TVMManager);

            //Applies the marker.
            marker.ApplyMarkers(UnknownVariableAction.Skip);
            return book;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This is not a [real question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145677/what-is-a-real-question) for here. Did you try anything so far? Show your effort first so people might show their. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 3):

SyncFusion themselves provide a method to convert an Excel spreadsheet to PDF if you have their PDF section of Essential Studio.

A sample of how to do the conversion is here:

http://asp.syncfusion.com/Windows/demos/reporting/pdf/Import%20to%20PDF/Excel%20to%20PDF/Sample.aspx

In its simplest form, it looks like this:

```
//Open the Excel document to convert
ExcelToPdfConverter converter=new ExcelToPdfConverter("Sample.xlsx");
//Convert Excel document into PDF document
PdfDocument pdfDoc = converter.Convert();
pdfDoc.Save("ExceltoPDF.pdf");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Currently, In Syncfusion Essential XlsIO WINRT control does not support for converting the excel worksheets to an PDF document.

Thanks,
Sridhar.S

Comment: If convertion is not possible then Is there any way to create new pdf. I tried syncfusion but its so much difficult.